# Multiprocess Pool vs asyncio.run_in_executor

Tags: python, multithreading, scikit-learn, multiprocessing

### Overview

I am trying to parallelize a text classification project that certainly takes too long to run completely in series. I've attempted two possible variations of this that I believe function similarly and am curious about the results of each that I've seen in the Resource Monitor.

### The First Solution

The first thing that I tried was to use Python's `asyncio` with `run_in_executor()`. This is a method I had used previously to parallelize some simple jobs, so I thought I'd give it a try. It looks like this:

```
cores = cpu_count()
qty = len(data)
last = 0

coros = []
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
for i in range(cores):
    top = ceil((qty * (i + 1)) / cores)
    cor = loop.run_in_executor(None, vect.transform, data[last: top])
    last = int(top)

vectors = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*coros))
loop.close()
```

My understanding is that this code creates a default pool of *threads*, runs `func` on each chunk of the data and returns the results in the same order they came in. I expected this to top out my cpu but it only ever seems to run at 15%. Looking at the individual processors, only half of them are engaged and only at around 20%-30% each. This remains even until I get too impatient and stop the program or try to change something to streamline it.

### The Second Solution

The second method I'm employing utilizes the `multiprocessing` module and its `Pool().map()`. This was new to me, but it appeared to function similarly to the first solution but using *processes*, so I thought it might utilize the processors in a manner closer to what I was expecting. That solution looks like this:

```
cores = cpu_count()
qty = len(data)
last = 0

chunks = []

for i in range(cores):
    top = ceil((qty * (i + 1)) / cores)

    chunks.append(data[last: top])
    last = int(top)

with Pool(processes=cores) as pool:
    vectors = pool.map(vect.transform, chunks)
```

I believe that this code should chunk the data, then open new *processes* to handle the data. Initially, the Resource Monitor does exactly as I would expect. CPU Usage goes to 100% and all cores show fully active. About 15s later, most of the cores are parked and two or three of them at around 15%. Several minutes after that, each core seems to fill up in pockets here and there averaging around 45% at any given time and eventually finishes.

### My expectation/The Question

Later in the program, I'm fitting the data to an sklearn classifier that has `n_jobs=-1`. When this happens all of the cores go 100%. This is what I would like to do. So I have a couple questions:

1. What is `sklearn` doing that I am not?
2. Is there something I'm overlooking in my approach that makes my expectations unrealistic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After running it a couple more times, the Second Method began to run as expected. I'm not exactly sure what made it change, but it is running the CPU at 100% now.

Also, after doing some digging, I came to the conclusion that `sklearn` probably uses `joblib` for parallelizing jobs. Looking into `joblib`, I found that the *default* [parallelizing code](http://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html) with `n_jobs=-1` is nearly identical to my Second Solution. `joblib` overall, however, is much more flexible and can be written in a cleaner manner for more complex use-cases.